# "Content Security Policy (CSP) Issue: 'require-trusted-types-for' causing errors"

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm currently implementing Content Security Policy (CSP) on my web application, and I've encountered an issue with the 'require-trusted-types-for' directive. The specific error I'm facing is [include the error message here, if available]. I have the following CSP header in place:

**Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'nonce-{your-nonce}' https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com; object-src 'none'; script-src-elem 'strict-dynamic'; trusted-types script; require-trusted-types-for script; report-uri /report-csp-violation;**

I have ensured that the nonce value is dynamically generated for each script tag, and the sources seem to be correctly defined. Despite this, I'm encountering issues, and I'm unsure how to resolve them.

Could someone please review my CSP header and provide insights into what might be causing the problem? Additionally, any guidance on how to troubleshoot or alternative approaches to achieve a secure CSP setup would be greatly appreciated.

***Here are some errors I'm facing.***

**CSP Header Contains Duplicate Directives:**
Error: Refused to apply a CSP header because it contains a duplicate 'script-src' directive.
Description: The CSP header should not contain duplicate directives. Ensure that each directive appears only once.

**CSP Header Contains Unrecognized Directives:**
Error: Refused to apply a CSP header because of an unrecognized or unsupported directive.
Description: Check for any typos or unsupported directives in your CSP header. Remove or correct any unrecognized directives.

**CSP Directive Value Contains Unsafe Sources:**
Error: Refused to apply inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
Description: The specified directive does not allow the source of the script. Adjust the directive to allow the necessary sources.

**Missing Required Trusted Types Directive:
Error: Refused to apply inline script because it requires 'trusted-types' to be enabled.
Description: Ensure that the 'trusted-types' directive is present in your CSP header, and that it's correctly configured.

**Nonce Mismatch:**
Error: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-some-nonce'".
Description: The nonce specified in the CSP header does not match the nonce attribute in the script tag.

**Hash Mismatch:**
Error: Refused to execute script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'sha256-hash'".
Description: The hash specified in the CSP header does not match the hash of the script.

**Wildcard Sources in Unsafe Context:**
Error: Refused to load script from 'unsafe-inline' because of Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
Description: Avoid the use of unsafe sources like 'unsafe-inline' or '*' in a script-src directive. Be specific about allowed sources.

**Report-Only Mode Warnings:**
Error: In report-only mode, warnings are logged to the console instead of blocking resources. Look for messages like Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource.

Thank you!